# How to create FileDataBodyPart from a JSONObject?

Tags: java, json, jersey, multipartform-data

I am trying to invoke a `multipart/form-data` request which is accepting a `FileDataBodyPart (application/json)` as parameter using `Jersey` client. At client-side, I have the input data in the form of `JSONObject`. Is there a way to convert the given `JSONObject` to type `File`(in-memory) so that I can create and send `FileDataBodyPart` to server?

I have tried it with `StreamDataBodyPart` with media type as `application/json` also, which is returning `BAD_REQUEST(400)`. I also tried creating temporary in-memory file from `JSONObject`, but the the input parameter shows null data at server-side.

Please ignore any format or language related mistake.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). You're asking how to create a FileDataBodyPart but you said you also tried StreamDataBodyPart, which I assume means that FileDataBodyPart is _not_ a requirement. How do you know using a FileDataBodyPart would even be the right solution to your problem? If you describe the main problem at a higher level, maybe we could help you solve your actual problem, instead of this one, which seems like not the right solution IMO.

Comment: Hi @PaulSamsotha , I tried creating FileDataBodyPart  after reading a local json file and passing it as File parameter. The request processed successfully. When I tried reading JSONObject to InputStream and passed it as parameter to create StreamDataBodyPart, it said BAD REQUEST. So, FileDataBodyPart is a requirement.

Comment: The problem on higher level is just invoking a multipart/form-data POST request using Jersey Client. The request has some associated headers and two files in request body. One is pdf file and another is a json file. @PaulSamsotha

Comment: What is the required content-type of the part(s) you are having trouble with? What is the code you are currently using?

Comment: If it requires application/json, You can use FormDataBodyPart, passing APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE as the media type, and just call toString on the JSONObject to pass to it

Comment: I was needed to set the media type for each specific bodypart. After I added application/json to the required bodypart, it worked. Thanks.